# Request after request ajax and jquery using $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am very new to Jquery and ajax so please be kind.
i am making a request to the server using jquery $.ajax, the ajax pulls the image from the image id stored on the server/database when the user clicks on a thumbnail of which there are loads. All works fine except with the following code i can only click on any of the thumbnails once to load the big picture from the database, after that no other thumbnail works.
Can anyone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getimage(data){
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function(){
    $(img).hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "name.php?",
        data: "name=" + data,
        success: function(){
            $("#loader").removeClass("loading").append(img);
            $(img).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}).attr("src", data +".jpg");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Image Loading</h1>
<div id="loader" class="loading">

</div>
<a href="name.php?name=image1" id="image1" onclick="getimage('image1'); return false;"/><img src="image1_th.jpg" /></a>
<a href="name.php?name=image2" id="image2" onclick="getimage('image2'); return false;" /><img src="image2_th.jpg" /></a>
<a href="name.php?name=image3" id="image3" onclick="getimage('image3'); return false;"/><img src="image3_th.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: No have have nothing, it's like the action is one time only

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be working. Can you set up a demo? Also it is considered better practice to separate all JavaScript from HTML, so you would be better attaching the onclick handlers to the anchors using jQuery.

Comment: No worries, i have seen bit regarding that.

Comment: I'm uploading now to the demo

Comment: http://www.digital-juice.co.uk/stack/
Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function getimage(data){
var img = new Image();
$(img).load(function(){
    $(img).hide();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "name.php?",
        data: "name=" + data,
        success: function(){
             $("#loader").html(''); // you need to remove the old image
            $("#loader").removeClass("loading").append(img);
            $(img).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
}).attr("src", data +".jpg");
```